# Apache Alias - PHP files are downloaded by browser instead

Tags: php, apache, plesk

PHP files are downloaded by browser instead, when I visiting http://domain.com/hk.

but http://domain.hk works fine

======= Platform: CentOS 6 (Plesk Panel)

My vhost.conf under domain.com

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php

Alias "/hk" "/var/www/vhosts/domain.hk/httpdocs"
<Directory "/hk">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: need `SetHandler` for php-files like `<FilesMatch \.php$>SetHandler application/x-httpd-php</FilesMatch>`

Comment: Thank, deadooshka. I tried, but not working

Answer (score 0):

There is an issues with your PHP-handler. Try to remove that from your vhost config and check it.

And also let me know which php version is installed on your server ?

Comment: Thanks man, The result is same after I removed PHP handler from vhost config which is autogened by Plesk Panel 11.5.30 , btw my php version is 5.3.3 and PHP handled by Fast-CGI default